# How to select range with input user in list

Tags: python, list, range

I want to select a range between elements in a list, but instead of putting, for example, item 7, I put what I'm seeing in elements. The number between 'document' and '35621' changes, I need to convert these numbers to a range (I think?)

I don't really know how to make this.

```
data_input = raw_input("\nEnter range: \n")

my_list = ['document-452-35621', 'document-453-35621', 'document-454-35621', 'document-455-35621', 'document-456-35621', 'document-457-35621', 'document-458-35621', 'document-459-35621', 'document-460-35621']

print my_list[5:9]
```

For example, in my list I have:

```
[
    'document-452-35621', 
    'document-453-35621', 
    'document-454-35621', 
    'document-455-35621', 
    'document-456-35621', 
    'document-457-35621', 
    'document-458-35621', 
    'document-459-35621', 
    'document-460-35621'
]
```

I enter in choice input : `456-460`

The result would be:

```
[
    'document-456-35621',
    'document-457-35621',
    'document-458-35621',
    'document-459-35621',
    'document-460-35621'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
my_list = [
    'document-452-35621',
    'document-453-35621',
    'document-454-35621',
    'document-455-35621',
    'document-456-35621',
    'document-457-35621',
    'document-458-35621',
    'document-459-35621',
    'document-460-35621'
]

data_input = input("\nEnter range: \n").split('-') # ['456', '460']
lower_bound = int(data_input[0]) # 456
upper_bound = int(data_input[1]) # 460

new_list = []
for item in my_list:
    if lower_bound <= int(item.split('-')[1]) <= upper_bound:
        new_list.append(item)

print(new_list)
```

Or alternatively, you can use [List Comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) and do it like this:

```
new_list = [item for item in my_list if lower_bound <= int(item.split('-')[1]) <= upper_bound]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[
    'document-456-35621',
    'document-457-35621',
    'document-458-35621',
    'document-459-35621',
    'document-460-35621'
]
```

I can see that you're using `Python 2`, so the only difference I think is with the `print` and `raw_input`. However, since "[Python 2.7 will not be maintained past 2020,](https://pythonclock.org/)" I would encourage you to use `Python 3` and above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will do more search about list, yes I know about python 2x, i will move on python3 soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

please see the code as below:
`[n for n in my_list if int(ranges[0]) <= int(n.split('-')[1]) <= int(ranges[1])]`

This is the full code.

```
data_input = input("\nEnter range: \n")

my_list = ['document-452-35621', 'document-453-35621', 'document-454-35621', 'document-455-35621', 'document-456-35621', 'document-457-35621', 'document-458-35621', 'document-459-35621', 'document-460-35621']

ranges = data_input.split('-')
result = [n for n in my_list if int(ranges[0]) <= int(n.split('-')[1]) <= int(ranges[1])]
print (result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast input to int:

```
my_list = [
'document-452-35621',
'document-453-35621',
'document-454-35621',
'document-455-35621',
'document-456-35621',
'document-457-35621',
'document-458-35621',
'document-459-35621',
'document-460-35621'
]

data_input = input("\nEnter range: \n").split('-')

print([x for x in my_list if int(data_input[0])<=int(x.split('-')[1]))<=int(data_input[1])]
```

the output will be:

```
['document-456-35621',
'document-457-35621', 
'document-458-35621', 
'document-459-35621', 
'document-460-35621']
```